# Save data to multiple database table with one model cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have two database with same table.

db1.wafer_types Table:-

```
ID    waferType   name
1071  req_1       req_1_name
1072  req_2       req_2_name
1073  req_3       req_3_name
```

db2.wafer_types Table:-

```
ID   wafer_type_id    waferType   name
1    1071  req_1       req_1_name
2    1072  req_2       req_2_name
3    1073  req_3       req_3_name
```

Model(WaferTypesTable)

```
class WaferTypesTable extends Table {    
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('wafer_types');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');        
    }
}
```

Entity(WaferType)

```
class WaferType extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
         '*' => true,
        'id' => false
    ];
}
```

Controller Function :-

```
public function waferTypeHistory($id,$userid){        
    $waferType = $this->WaferTypes->find()->where(['id'=>$id])->hydrate(false)->toArray();          
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default_history');
    $this->WaferTypes->setConnection($connection);
    $waferTypeHistory = $this->WaferTypes->newEntity();        
    $waferTypeHistory = $this->WaferTypes->patchEntity($waferTypeHistory, $waferType[0]);
    $waferTypeHistory->wafer_type_id = $id;
    $this->WaferTypes->save($waferTypeHistory);
    return true;
}
```

data inserted successfully in db2.wafer_types table. but wafer_type_id filed getting value '0'. i am assigning value to it, but it always getting value '0'.
Any idea why its getting value '0' every time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the cached schema, `db1.wafer_types` has no `wafer_type_id` column, hence the ORM will not include it in the saving process.

You can test it by unsetting the schema after changing the connection, like this:

```
$this->WaferTypes->setSchema(null);
```

I'd suggest using a separate (extended) model instead, which you can configure to use the `db2` connection by default. Fumbling with connections and schemas all the time seems like a rather unstable solution.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Metadata Caching](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-metadata-cache)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Configuring Connections](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#configuring-connections)**